# Ring extension and Jacobson rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> If $R\subseteq S$ are commutative rings, is it a fact that $R$ is a Jacobson ring if and only if $S$ is so?

I guess the contraction of maximal and prime ideals of $S$ may be helpful in this regards. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take $R=\left\{ \frac{a}{2b+1} : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right\} \subseteq S=\mathbb{Q}$. $R$ is not a Jacobson ring, but $S$ is.

Comment: Thank you! If we add the condition of "$S$ being integral over $R$" (which is not the case in your example), is the answer in affirmative?

Comment: One direction is in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38413/integral-extension-of-a-jacobson-ring

Comment: For the converse, how should we use the hypothesis that $S$ is integral over $R$? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true that if $R\subset S$ is an integral extenson of rings and if $S$ is Jacobson, then $R$ is Jacobson too. [For the converse, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38429/3217)]
Indeed, let $\mathfrak p \subset R$ be a prime ideal and $\mathfrak P \subset S$ a prime [lying over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Integral_extensions) $\mathfrak p $ .
Since $S$ is Jacobson, we can write $\mathfrak P=\cap \mathfrak M_i$ for some family of maximal ideals $\mathfrak M_i \subset S$.
But then $$\mathfrak p =R\cap \mathfrak P=R\cap (\cap \mathfrak M_i)=\cap (R\cap \mathfrak M_i)$$
Now $\mathfrak m_i:=R\cap \mathfrak M_i$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ (by the integrality of $R\subset S$) and thus we have written an arbitrary prime ideal $\mathfrak p \subset R$ as the intersection $\mathfrak p=\cap (R\cap \mathfrak M_i)=\cap \mathfrak m_i$ of some maximal ideals $\mathfrak m_i\subset R$.
 Thus $R$ is Jacobson.